# How to use RegularExpressionValidator on a TextBox for the first number?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have an TextBox in which i have to put my identity card number. 
The thing about it is that i use an RegularExpressionValidator to have the FIRST number 1 or 2. And to be maximum of 13 numbers. E.g: 134563964294 or 2492048639193 ,  as i said the first number to be 1 or 2 and in total they have to be 13 numbers.

**I tried something like: [1-2]/d{13} but only the part for 13 numbers in total worked. I don't know how to make the first number 1 or 2 .**

I couldn't find anything useful on internet or here, on stackoverflow.

Can you guys please, help me with this regex problem ?

Also , i use Microsoft Web Developer 2010 express , if that is something important.

Comment: Your first number will not match as it consists of 12 digits. You could use `^[12][0-9]{12}$` See https://regex101.com/r/tp4Whe/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[1-2][0-9]{12,12}$
```

> ^ asserts position at start of a number
>
> [1-2] forces one digit to be 1 or 2
>
> [0-9]{12,12} says min/max of 12 digits after this first digit above
>
> $ asserts position at the end of a line so they can't run over

If you ommit the ^ or $, you can have it go more than 13 digits

Test it out [on RegExr](http://regexr.com/540ce)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex you were going for is `^[12]\d{0,12}$`. The symbols at the start and end captures the start and end of the string and then the rest is quite similar to your attempt. Feel free to ask any specific questions in the comments or in a new thread!

Comment: ^[1-2]\d{1,12}$

Comment: Hey Cagri, I believe that [1-2] is the same thing as [12]. I would not know which one would be quicker off of the top of my head, but I appreciate the contibution. I will edit my post accordingly

Comment: @CagriD.Kaynar it worked the way you said. With the regular expression validator i thought i would neet something like (0[1-2])\d{13} but your idea worked. Thanks a lot guys !